# Icon misplaced in dynamic menu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I am trying to create a Dynamic menu in WPF.
The below code is working fine, but the problem is it is not showing Icon image in the left side but with the header section.
Here is my XAML code

```xml
<Window x:Class="DynamicMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"          
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DynamicMenu.MenuItemViewModels"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicMenu"      
        mc:Ignorable="d"       
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildMenuItems}" Header="Menu" >
                    <MenuItem.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuItemViewModel}"                                              ItemsSource="{Binding ChildMenuItems}">
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Header}" >
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding IconFileName}" Height="16" />
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.Resources>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>       
</Window>
```

Now, it looks like as below. But I want to show the icon on the left side.

[image]

Comment: When you use a menuItem as is, the icon it appears on the left so check your (in this post not included) dependencies

Comment: To trace it down I have created a sample application which has only one view without any style. But that is behaving the same way..
It is happening when I use HierarchicalDataTemplate and creating the menu dynamically.
If you like then you can have a look at the whole project here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HV4ACDTdK7tgnltwYUmc6Jm-tfoK31CP

Comment: @DenisSchaf  the code I mentioned in the question is also from the sample project I created.